# Android web Service

Tags: java, android, web-services

```
public class NineJan2012Activity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;
        String result1=null;
        int lineno=0;
        //http post
       // StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        // StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            lineno++;
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/food.php");
            lineno++;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(0);
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            lineno++;
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            lineno++;
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            lineno++;
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            lineno++;
            is = entity.getContent();
            lineno++;
            Log.e("log_tag", "Success in http connection"+lineno);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString()+lineno);
            }

    }

}
```

In this code I have an error on line `HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`

> android.os.NetworkOnMianThreadException

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to run your network stuff on another thread.